# d3js nested selection unexpected behavior

Tags: nested, d3.js

I've been fiddling around with the basic nested selection example in the documentation and I've discovered a behaviour that I cannot explain.

Here's the example with added logging (formatted as spoilers):

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var matrix = [
        [11975, 5871, 8916, 2868],
        [1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
        [8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
        [1013, 990, 940, 6907]
    ];

    var tr = d3.select("body")
        .append("table")
        .selectAll("tr")
        .data(matrix, function(d, i) {
```

> console.log(d); // called 4 times, printing **[11975, 5871, 8916, 2868]** and **[1951, 10048, 2060, 6171]** and **[8010, 16145, 8090, 8045]** and **[1013, 990, 940, 6907]**, which is nice

```
           return i;
           })
        .enter().append("tr")
        .attr("test", function(d) {
```

> console.log(d); // again, called 4 times, printing **[11975, 5871, 8916, 2868]** and **[1951, 10048, 2060, 6171]** and **[8010, 16145, 8090, 8045]** and **[1013, 990, 940, 6907]**, which is nice

```
           return "test";
           });

    var td = tr.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(d) {
```

> console.log(d); // I'm expecting this to be called 4*4=16 times, printing **11975** and then **5871** and then **8916** and then **2868** and then **1951** and so on. Not the case! This line prints the same as above!

```
            return d;
        })
        .enter().append("td")
        .text(function(d) {
```

> console.log(d); // this prints exaclty what I'm expecting: **11975** and then **5871** and then **8916** and then **2868** and then **1951** and then **10048** and then **2060** and then **6171** and so on.

```
            return d;
        });
```

Why is spoiler#3 printing the matrix elements instead of the matrix sub elements?

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is: because the `<td>` elements haven't been created yet.

I ran your code followed by these snippets:

```
console.log(tr);
tr.selectAll("td").data(function(d){
  console.log(d); // equivalent to spoilers 1/2/3
  return d;
});

console.log(td);
td.selectAll("td").data(function(d){
  console.log(d); // equivalent to spoiler 4
  return d;
});
```

The data isn't bound to each `<td>` until the enter-append in the last chunk. After that, the `tr` variable is still 4 `<tr>` elements, now with 4 child `<td>` elements each, while the `td` variable is actually 4 arrays of `<td>` elements. They have differently structured data associated with them.

Comment: It would then seem that the second call to data() is some sort of special case, in which the matrix sub elements are hoisted into the enter() selection instead of the update() selection (as opposed to a non-nested data join...?